# Jquery "val" setter doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
var output = $('#output');

function NumberButtClick()
 {
$('.numberButt').click(
    function ()
    {
        if(output.val() === '')
        {
         output.val(this.value);        
        }

        else
        {
            var entered = output.val();
            entered = entered + this.value;
            output.val(entered);
        }
    }
);
```

the if block works fine it outputs the value on the textbox (output - is textbox). but when I enter the number button again. the else block doesn't work it just leaves the output as it was

Comment: Ifs your code valid? `var output = $('#output);`  should be `var output = $('#output');`

Comment: @LeGEC Do not rewrite OP's code....there is a chance that the missing quote could be the problem, let the OP edit that if it is the problem

Comment: @Anton : it's clearly a typo (see "the if block works fine" part). It will avoid useless answer such as "you are missing a ' "

Comment: @LeGEC It could be a typo, and it could not be aswell thats why you let the OP edit that himself...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have forgotten  to to an '

```
var output = $('#output');
$('.numberButt').click(
function ()
{
    if(output.val() === '')
    {
     output.val($(this).val());        // i think you forget $ 
    }

    else
    {
        var entered = output.val();
        entered = entered + $(this).val(); //also here
        output.val(entered);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.value === $(this).val()`

Comment: did your function has .value attribute ??

Comment: That's not my question.

Comment: sorry i have seen undefined  i thought that this is the result of ==

Comment: hmm that's worked can anyone explain why doesn't the previous one worked?

Comment: @luka When do you call the `NumberButtClick()` function?

Comment: @luka Do you call the function somewhere else? If yes, that's the root of the problem as you are attaching several click handlers.

Comment: I have 9 buttons and I am attaching this functiion to their click handlers

Comment: I'd tried this code and it worked fine var entered = output.val() ; var numb = this.value; entered = entered + numb ; output.val(entered);

Comment: you know why i have asked you before that if your function has .value 
because when you say this.value  it seeks in the current scope  for this with this property (this of the function) not the object  but when you you mention $(this).val() it gets you the value of the object

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
 $('.numberButt').on('click', function ()
    {

        output.val(( output.val()? output.val():'' ) + $(this).val());

     });
```

edit : meaning instead of the function numberbuttonclickwhatever (not just instead of the click event handler in the function) therefore wrapped in a `jQuery(function($,undefined) {})`

Answer (score 0):

From what I tested, the idea behind your code works : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfC6B/1/)  (your original code would actually concatenate strings : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfC6B/)).

```
var output = $('#output');

$('.numberButt').click(
    function ()
    {
        if(output.val() === '')
        {
         output.val(this.value);        
        }

        else
        {
            var entered = parseInt(output.val(), 10);
            entered = entered + parseInt(this.value, 10);
            output.val(entered);
        }
    }
);
```

In what part of your code do you call your `NumberButtClick()` function ? How is your html set up ?